# Where to buy a 48VDC power supply for a server?

Tags: hardware, electrical-power

Where can one buy a power supply for a server that has -48VDC power input (like [this one, for example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SGI-Rackable-Systems-C1000-1U-half-depth-Server-4GB-2x-AMD-Dual-Core-Opteron-280-/281153359064?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item41760bccd8))?
Which power supplies would you recommend?

EDIT:
I am looking into integrating a server like the one in the link (which has a 48VDC power input, visible top-left in the photo) into a small server rack. Detailed information about the server is provided [in the link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SGI-Rackable-Systems-C1000-1U-half-depth-Server-4GB-2x-AMD-Dual-Core-Opteron-280-/281153359064?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item41760bccd8).

[image]

I don't have an external -48VDC power supply. The server is used and does not come with an external power supply, and from an eBay search it seems that these power supplies are quite expensive.

To rephrase my question:
Should I be looking for a 48VDC, or is it more feasible to replace the power supply within the server with a 220V power supply?

Comment: Welcome to serverfault! Product and service recommendations are off topic. Please check out the tour at http://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems lazy, in the absence of any real details, specifications or manufacturer information.

Comment: The 48VDC input IS the power supply.  The 48VDC input is from running the computer from a DC PDU/Bus, or a Battery (Since 120/240v are more expensive to achieve with batteries).  You can find the product you need if you just google "48V DC PDU" (Don't use the Negative Sign! Google will exclude those results really making it difficult!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think it is alternatively possible to replace the component in the top-right with a more standard 220V AC power supply?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend buying from the manufacturer of the server and matching the specifications of the existing power supply, assuming you're looking for a replacement.

If the manufacturer is no longer reachable or in business, I'd try to source components from eBay or off-lease/used hardware vendors.

Can you provide *any* detail on what you're working with?